# Clean up the [interference]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

[interference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interference)This tag, with no description, has a combination of questions misspelling "inference", questions about radio(?) interference (largely working around some kind of Mac WIFI/BT issue), and all sorts of other random questions about one thing "interfering" with another (concurrency problems, GUI visual interference, etc.). I've done some retagging and deleted it from some questions, but I could use a bit of help.

Comment: That made me stumble over [tag:magnetic]. The questions there are about as diverse as the nonsensical excerpt invites.

Comment: @Deduplicator `"Magnetic points are used to control a flow of particles..."` Umm.... What? What on Earth is a 'magnetic point,' anyway? Also, I think there are more uses for magnetism than controlling a flow of particles.

Comment: @Deduplicator, note that some questions tagged [tag:magnetic] should be tagged [tag:magnetometer].

Comment: @reirab, you should note that too.

Comment: @Deduplicator, all the ones I could catch.

Comment: @dfeuer Yeah, that makes sense. Thanks for retagging those. As far as the nonsensical tag wiki excerpt, is there a way to nuke that? I tried just deleting it as an edit, but it wouldn't let me submit it blank.

Comment: @reirab, I believe the tag is deleted after a day or two.

Answer (score 8):

[It's toast!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interference)