# End the [conflict]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

In the process of [cleaning up the [interference]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284243/clean-up-the-interference) I've discovered another horribly generic [conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/conflict) going on. The tag info reads

> is a generic tag for questions dealing with conflicts between programming elements; such as applications, functions, etc.

This is obviously useless, but it has 1288 questions and even a synonym. Let's get rid of this thing, shall we?

Comment: But I'm an expert in conflict.  People have even said so themselves. :(

Comment: @iCodez, I'd dispute that. :-P

Comment: Once you've ended the `conflict` here, can we send you to the middle east? I hear they could use some help.

Comment: You have to make clearer why you think this tag is useless and you haven't shown a proper action what should happen with the questions. Simply removing the tag doesn't improve anything. You may propose some retags such as to [name-conflict] or [conflicting-libraries]. I don't see why [conflict] is so harmful that it has to be burninated. Nobody's getting worked up over [algorithm], but it is equally broad if not broader.

Comment: @ArtjomB., [tag:algorithm] helps classify questions (it's actually a tag I follow). [tag:conflict] does not. It is unlikely that anyone would wish to follow it or ignore it, and no one can be an expert at it. It therefore does not meet the requirements for a useful tag.

Answer (score 5):

It does appear mostly useless. By itself is surely useless. But something tagged with `[x] [y] [conflict]` or even `[x] [conflict]` is sometimes suggestive however. The problem is that SO/SE doesn't handle adjective or predicate tags well, especially for the purpose of following them. But I can, for example, search for [`[conflict] [c]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/conflict+c) and it returns mostly questions about C types/names conflicts. YMMV if this is really useful in the C case because there's also a more precise [name-collision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/name-collision) tag and even/also [incompatibletypeerror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/incompatibletypeerror).

Beware that there's also an [incompatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/incompatibility) tag, which is just as generic as [conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/conflict). Perhaps a good way to deal with these two is to have a pop-up suggestion like for [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) suggesting a list of narrower tags, e.g. "For naming conflicts use name-collision" etc. Someone would have to systematize and compile that list though.

I see there's nothing along the lines of a "dll-hell" tag... I'm not sure what should be used for library conflicts; perhaps just [dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dependencies), but this also seems rather generic; compare [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27932825/resolve-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libselinux-so-1-in-ubuntu-14-04-lt) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27938527/why-are-dependency-graphs-not-represented-as-bi-directional-acyclic-graphs), both tagged with [dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dependencies). Perhaps create [dependencies-conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dependencies-conflict) as the universal version of dll-hell; it would surely apply to questions like [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827335/different-versions-of-the-same-dependency-in-maven); perhaps create [version-conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/version-conflict) as a synonym for that given how they're both used in [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395004/how-to-use-two-versions-of-jar-in-my-java-project) for example. An the suggestion list should definitely include [merge-conflict-resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/merge-conflict-resolution) as it seems to be one of the common [mis]uses of "conflict", e.g. in [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825115/darcs-conflicts) or [a bunch more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/conflict+git).

So to summarize what I said, split/suggest at least the following for [conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/conflict):

- [name-collision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/name-collision) / [incompatibletypeerror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/incompatibletypeerror)
- [dependencies-conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dependencies-conflict) / [version-conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/version-conflict) (both to be created)
- [merge-conflict-resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/merge-conflict-resolution)