# A systematic approach to burnination

Tags: support, tags, burninate-system

I'm fairly new to meta, but I have noticed over the past few months that a large proportion of highly upvoted questions (those I see through "Hot Meta Posts") tend to be tag-burnination-related.

It seems as if there are a large number of bad tags out there and it often seems that people are selecting tags based on making ironic titles (see [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255169/i-want-to-delete-the-internet) and [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284369/end-the-conflict)).

On Stack Overflow, the last 112 pages of tags have no questions on them. Do we need them? Also, should we further restrict the ability to create new tags?

For my specific request: I think there should be an expedited way to delete tags. If the number of questions on any tag is lower than some `n`, say 10, then it can be flagged and dealt with a question.

Comment: Note that tags with no questions *are* cleaned up by the roomba. It just takes a little while :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Most of the tags with NO questions are actually [*tag synonyms*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-how-do-they-work), which will never have any questions *by-design!* They exist to guide taggers to use canonical tags, and the system automatically replaces them with the tag they're synonymized with whenever they're used.

Beyond that, [unused tags are deleted every day at 3:00 UTC](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19753/how-can-we-get-rid-of-misspelled-and-unused-or-zombie-tags). Tags used on only a single question are removed 6 months after their creation, [*unless* someone has taken the time to write a tag wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127700/do-not-expire-single-use-tags-that-have-a-tag-wiki).

For all other tags, they can be removed by following the instructions here: [When to burninate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191)