# How new are "new" tags?

Tags: support, tags

If we go to the *"Tags"* section of the main site and click on the [new](https://stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=new) tab we are presented with the tags that were most recently created. One of these is the [fullstack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fullstack) tag, which currently has one (off-topic) [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42909148/6214222) with three views that was asked 5 hours ago. The [new tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=new) tab also indicates that the tag was created 5 hours ago.

[image]

However, if you hover over the tag you'll see that it shows 167 followers for this tag:

[image]

How is this possible? There are multiple possibilities I could think of:

- The tag is just showing the wrong number of followers (= bug)
- The tag is not new and has gathered 167 followers - **but**, don't tags with no questions at some point get [automatically deleted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286404/6214222)? And why would it show up in the "new" tags section then? (= maybe bug)
- The user who indroduced the tag did a really good job of hyping it up on his social media or in some chat for the past 5 hours and 167 people decided to follow it without even checking out the only question there is. (= everything ok but really weird)

Or is there something else I'm missing? Can people maybe auto-follow tags with specific keywords?

There might also just be people going to the new tags tab to find new tags to follow, in which case there would obviously be no problem at all but 167 seems quite much for 5 hours and an off-topic question.

Comment: My guess is that it existed a while ago and got all those followers, then it got burninated because it's off-topic, and now it was resurrected keeping the previous followers.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

"Followers" refers to the sum of two things:

1. Folks who have the tag (or a wildcard that matches it) in their "favorite tags" list.
2. Folks who are getting emailed about new questions in the tag (driven behind the scenes by [a filter](https://stackexchange.com/filters) on stackexchange.com).

Now, here's the kicker: neither one of those actually requires the tag to *exist*. You can add [sweetcuppincakes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sweetcuppincakes) to your favorites on Stack Overflow, or create a filter for the same on SE.com, and the system will happily record that fact and do nothing else... Until the tag actually exists.

That said, what probably happened here is that folks added that tag to their favorites a few years back when it existed previously, and never bothered removing it after it got removed from the system (back in '15, according to the logs).

Comment: Maybe there is should be a cleanup cron job or something that cleans up tags from users preferences after it gets deleted?

Comment: That's a little bit dodgy, and also doesn't help at all if you have wildcards.

Comment: No, do not delete preferences that I have personally made! The vs6 tag might be dead but I'm a "Visual Studio 6 forever" kind of guy.

Comment: I wish I could upvote again for "sweet cuppin' cakes"

Comment: @Feathercrown Dang, if only I had a spare unnamed JS framework lying around...

Comment: @Dragomok If you have the chance. please make this happen.